# How do i moniter CONTROL KEY press event on firefox using only javascript?

Tags: events, keypress, onkeypress

i have code that can monitor control key press event on chrome but its not working on firefox

this works fine on chrome

```
onkeypress = (e) =>{
console.log(e);
if(e.ctrlKey && e.code == "KeyZ"){
    document.write("do somthing")
} }
```

this is what iam getting on chrome

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "", code: "KeyZ", location: 0, ctrlKey: true, …}
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey#browser_compatibility, this should work fine in Firefox. Are you sure this is not failing due to the second part of that condition here?

Comment: i am positive , i am trying to log the event on key press but its not working when i press cntrl key @CBroe

Comment: Are you talking about _just_ pressing the ctrl key, without anything else? Then this event does not fire to begin with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event: _“The keypress event is fired when a key **that produces a character value** is pressed down.”_

Comment: i am not get any log when i press control key with some other key either @CBroe ..

Comment: The example under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event#examples works for normal keys for me in Firefox, but doesn’t add any output, when ctrl is pressed at the same time. Maybe you should take not of the big, fat deprecation warning on top of that page first of all, before investing any more time into this?

Comment: i want to do undo and redo any suggestions how can i do that , thanks for the help  @CBroe

Comment: I don’t think it makes much sense to try and implement any custom functionality, in combination with the ctrl key - that triggers a lot of actions by default in current browsers already. For example, while testing the example mentioned in the link above in Firefox, I pressed ctrl + h, and the history panel opened … Even if you manage to deal with that, you’d still probably be breaking default functionality users are already used to - so you’d force them to “learn” something different, just for the context of your site. Does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: If you want a undo/redo functionality in some sort of editor component or similar - then I’d provide _buttons_ for that.

Comment: well , sounds good , thanks @CBroe